# Should I define a separate interface for clarity rather than implementing Supplier<T>?

Tags: java, object-oriented, clean-code, clean-architecture

Let's say you have to meet some prerequisites before doing something. For that, I think implementing `Supplier<Boolean>` is a great candidate since it's widely used, and quick to understand. But, my colleague argues that since it's normally used for lambda definition, defining a separate interface is more clear. Should I follow his suggestion?

Comment: Can you explain more about your use case? If it's a situation where you would typically not use a lambda, I would say your colleague is right, but with judgement calls like this, more background information is usually better.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a custom interface with a single method (Single Abstract Method, SAM) and annotate it with `@FunctionalInterface` such that is usable as a lambda function, but has semantic meaning (by naming the interface and method).

For example:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface UserRequirement {

  boolean checkRequirement();

}
```

Some examples are here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces

---

Another option which may suit your use case better:

> you have to meet some prerequisites before doing something

sounds like a requirement or a check. This is ususally implemented with the concept of `Predicate`, a function which returns a boolean. `Predicate` is built into the Java standard library: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html. The advantage of `Predicate` is that `Predicate`s are composable with `and` and `or` (default) methods. Combining your business requirements with these methods results in clean and readable code.